# $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in [0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=\infty\Rightarrow \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-a_n)=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> > Consider a sequence $(a_n)_{\in\mathbb{N}}\in [0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ with $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=\infty$. Show that then 
> >     $$
> > \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-a_n)=0.
> > $$

How can I show that?

My idea is to show it by contradiction.

I assume $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in [0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=\infty$. Assuming, $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-a_i)\neq 0$. Then $(1-a_i)\neq 0~\forall~i\geq 1\Leftrightarrow a_i\neq 1~\forall~i\geq 1$.

Consider f.e. $a_i:=\frac{1}{2^i}$, then $a_i\in [0,1]~\forall~i\geq 1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i=1<\infty$.

But I was assuming, that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i=\infty$.

So there must be at least one $i\geq 1$ with $a_i=1$ and then $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}(1-a_i)=0$.

Does this make any sense? To be honest, I am not sure!

Comment: My answer was incorrect, and there is no reason that any of the $a_i$ should be $1$.

Comment: The deduction is wrong, if the sequence is any constant in the open interval $(0,1)$, then it sum diverges, the product of the "one-minuses" tends to 0 (it's just the powers of that constant), but no element is 1, ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the logarithm of a partial product and use the inequality $\ln (1+x)<x$.

Comment: Do not know exactly what you mean: $\ln(\prod_{i=1}^{N}(1-a_i))=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\ln(1-a_i)$ and now?

Comment: And now apply the inequality to each term in the sum.

Comment: Okay, then I have $\sum_{i=1}^{N}\ln(1-a_i)<\sum_{i=1}^{N}\ln(-a_i)$.

Comment: No. Where did that logarithm on the right come from? Are you familiar with the inequality I gave?

Comment: No, I am not familar with that. Taht's the point.

Comment: It comes from the fact that the logarithm is concave, so the graph of $y=\ln(1+x)$ lies below any of its tangents. The tangent at $x=0$ is given by $y=x$, therefore $\ln(1+x)<x$ (except when $x=0$, when there is inequality). In any case, there is no logarithm on the right.

Comment: Then I have $\ln(\prod_{i=1}^{N}(1-a_i))=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\ln(1-a_i)<\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i$?

Comment: With $x=-a_i$ in my inequality you get $\sum_{i=1}^n\ln(1-a_i)<\sum_{i=1}^n(-a_i)=-\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$, for sure?

Comment: Then I get $-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\ln(1-a_i)\geq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i=\infty$. Why follows from that that $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}(1-a_i)=0$?

Comment: The logarithm of something goes to $-\infty$. What does that say about the something? (Try applying the exponential function.)

Comment: I try. So I have $-\sum_{i=1}^{N}\ln(1-a_i)\geq\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i$. Now I consider $N\to\infty$, then I have $-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\ln(1-a_i)\geq \infty$. Does this mean $=\infty$ because it cannot be greater than $\infty$? If yes, I have $-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\ln(1-a_i)=\infty$ resp. $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\ln(1-a_i)=-\infty$. Then $\exp(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\ln(1-a_i))=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(1-a_i)=\exp(-\infty)=0$.

Comment: Good enough for now. We could discuss style and delivery, but this is not the place and the time.